# Displaying pandas dataframe rows in a single line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to display the rows of my pandas dataframe in a single line for each row. However, when the number of columns gets larger some columns shrink in width, forcing the contents of the columns onto the next line. How can I avoid this?

What I want:
[image]

What I do not want:
[image]

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How are you printing out the dataframe?  If you put it into a csv file you will defiantly get one row per line.

Comment: @PaulBrennan I am just displaying it in a Jupyter notebook and wanted to also get the display to be one row per line

Answer (score 0):

You may reduce the number of columns shown each time you call a dataframe with:

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = 7
```

I set it as `7` but feel free to change it.

Comment: This solution can allow the columns to be wide enough for low max column values and does make all of the rows display as single lines. However, I want to be able to have all of the rows display as a single and be able to see all of the columns (i.e. to still be able to scroll across the columns without changing how the rows are displayed)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 60)` and change the '60' to whatever you want.

Comment: I thought this would only work if the default max column width of 50 is exceeded, but I do not think this is the case here

Comment: follow up: I just tried this solution and it does not change the display